# how can I set the action url of the send button in swaggaer4spring-web?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using [swagger4spring-web](https://github.com/wkennedy/swagger4spring-web).
I applied my application well. It worked well. But If I load this web application to other server, it occurs the CORS problem.

Loading the apis from  my application, it works well. 
If I push the test button, "try it out", it failed because,It set "localhost" by default.

I want to set the action url of the button "try it out".

How can I fix it?  I want to change this url to the real ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix your CORS problem with a Spring RESTful application, look at [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). In some words, create following class and use it in you application :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

About swagger4spring-web : If you look at [this example code](https://github.com/wkennedy/swagger4spring-web-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/knappsack/swagger4springweb/controllers/ExampleDocumentationController.java), this class inherits from [ApiDocumentationController](https://github.com/wkennedy/swagger4spring-web/blob/master/src/main/java/com/knappsack/swagger4springweb/controller/ApiDocumentationController.java) and this last one provide a method called setBasePath(), use it to set the basePath of your swagger-api:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/documentation")
public class ExampleDocumentationController extends ApiDocumentationController {
    public ExampleDocumentationController() {
        ...
        setBasePath("http://www.youraddress.com");
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also set local IP address (fixed value or dynamic value).

Comment: Even if I tried setting basePath the constructor of the class extends ApiDocumentationController .it still set the localhost whenever I push the "try it out" button.  And I am using the source you linked. Help me...